# How do i pass $1 to sed?

Tags: command-line, sed, scripting

I'm using the following code to try to clean up some html files. `$1` should be the name of a directory. This works fine from the command line and the requested changes are made to the files in the directory. `echo` displays the `$directory` in both cases, however nothing is changed in the specified directory when used from the bash script. Why? How do I fix this?

```
#!/bin/bash
directory=$1
echo $directory
LC_CTYPE=C
sed -i.clean -f uncap-html.sed $directory/*.html
echo DONE
```

Comment: Are you trying to reference `$1` (in the context of the shell script) within `uncap-html.sed`?

Comment: no i'm just using $1 ($directory) to specify the folder that sed is acting upon.

Comment: Don't have a clue what I did but the above code is now working as desired.

Comment: Please get into the habit of double-quoting your variables: `directory="$1"` and `echo "$directory"` and `sed ... "$directory"/*.html`

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure why it is failing for you when same script **works as expected for me.**

**sed.sh**

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 directory=$1
  3 echo $directory
  4 LC_CTYPE=C
  5 sed -i.clean -f uncap-html.sed $directory/*.html
  6 echo DONE
```

**uncap-html.sed**

```
[gc13@oc1245342277 sh]$ cat uncap-html.sed 
s/z/o/g
[gc13@oc1245342277 sh]$
```

**1.html**

```
Hello
```

**2.html**

```
World
```

**Execution**

```
[gc13@oc1245342277 sh]$ cat *.html
Hellz
Wzrld
[gc13@oc1245342277 sh]$
```

You may want to try another approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="$1/*.html"
echo $FILES
LC_CTYPE=C
sed -i.clean -f uncap-html.sed $FILES
echo DONE
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now - go figure. Am clueless what i did differently.

Comment: Great. It must be an error of single character misplaced.